# Calling C++/CLI code from unmanaged C++ code

Tags: c++, .net-core, c++-cli, visual-studio-2022, googletest

I have a C++/CLI unit test project, containing Google tests. I build this project as a dll. I am exporting the following method from the dll:

```
   int runTests(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
       return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
   }
```

And I am calling this method from my unmanaged C++ exe as follows

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       return runTests(argc, argv);
   }
```

It works fine when I build my exe in (Visual Studio 2022) in release mode. But in debug mode once the `runTests` method has been called and the main function is about to exit, I get `Access violation reading location ...` in `coreclr.dll`. In VS it points to the following line in `gtest.cc`:

```
  TestInfo::~TestInfo() { delete factory_; }
```

My C++/CLI dll targets .NET Core 6 and is set up using the steps mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli.

Could someone point me to the possible things I should look at to resolve this issue?

PS. Rationale behind the above setup is try to solve the problem mentioned here: [Changing .NET framework 4.7.2 to .NET Core 6.0 for a C++/CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357967/changing-net-framework-4-7-2-to-net-core-6-0-for-a-c-cli-project)

Comment: Do you get the problem if you remove all the tests (still calling google test of course)?  How about if you build with the .NET Framework version that the tools were made for?

Comment: @BenVoigt Once I remove all tests (still calling RUN_ALL_TESTS) I do not get the error. Yes I still do get the error if I use .NET framework instead.

Comment: Looks like the umanaged code is trying to clean up something that isn't there anymore. I don't know the GoogleTest framework, unfortunately. Does `factory_` contain managed types ?

Comment: @nick yes the tests contain managed types.

Comment: You chose the wrong path (keeping that C++/CLI crap :-). Anyway, do you have some reproducing project?

Comment: Did you read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2022)? 
Did you follow every step?